# How to delete the contents of on premise wwwroot folder during Azure devops deployment through pipelines?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy my .Net code on IIS website through Azure devops pipeline. The deployment happens successfully if the wwwroot folder is kept empty before deployment, but if the wwwroot folder contains files, in that case the files are not overridden by the deployment process. I want to either delete the contents of the wwwroot folder before deployment or find some setting that helps me override the existing contents. Several questions have been asked on various forums and most of them suggest people to use the setting 'Remove additional files at destination', I tried the same but it does not work for me. Please suggest what can be done in this case.

[image]

Comment: @David Makogon how is this question related to Azure? Where's the hint that this web app is deployed to Azure?

Comment: @riQQ Azure DevOps is a feature of Azure. Build Agents, unless customized, are Azure-hosted. The OP's pipeline tasks are named "Web App" which (unless the naming is just random) corresponds to Azure Web Apps (though that pipeline step could be used for deploying to a VM). Given that Azure DevOps is an Azure-based service, it should be tagged as Azure. I don't see the value in removing the Azure Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear a folder or delete a file can be achieved via powershell scripts. You can add a powershell task before your deployment task to do the clean job.

Below script is just an example.
[image]

```
Try {
    Remove-Item -path "path\to\wwwroot\*" –recurse -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Warning, something failed! $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

However, I was no able to reproduce above issue. i tested **Remove additional files at destination**. It successfully deleted the non-matching files in the Web App zip package.
And i did a test to change the appsettings.json file in wwwroot folder, It got replaced too when i re-deployed my web.

Comment: Worked for me after adding the power shell task.

Answer (score 1):

you can set on the option "Remove additional files at destination" when you configure you release or pipeline

[image: Azure App Service devops release settings]

also you can set up the yaml file to do the same operation

```
steps:
- task: AzureWebAppDeployment
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure NonProd'
    WebAppName: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

where **RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag**: needs to be true